# install new splash screen and look and feel theme on KDE 5

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde

i'm new in Kubuntu KDE 5 and i can not find any document about to how to install new splash screen and look and feel theme on KDE 5. in previous version of kde we can simply click on get new theme button and we can download from internet. but in this version of kde i can not find this button

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The splash screen QML is stored in `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/lockscreen/LockScreen.qml`. You can either modify the backgroundPath or the image at that location. Note that it might get overwritten by updates, though.

There is lots of good information on SDDM [here](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67989-No-option-to-change-splash-look-and-feel-or-login-themes&p=371069&viewfull=1#post371069). There are a few [Look-And-Feel packs](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/121/order/latest) on the KDE Store, and you can try looking online for others. They should come with install instructions, otherwise just try copying files into `~/.local/share/plasma/look-and-feel/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using one of the built-in Breeze themes and you just want to change the small image that appears at the center of the splash screen, patch `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/splash/images/plasma.svgz`. An `.svgz` file is a `gzip`’d SVG file. XML 1.1 for the SVG markup is not supported; use XML 1.0. The `viewBox` has to be a square or it appears distorted.